# Does Transformer equivalent have anything to do with L12 when we have Lm?

Tags: transformer

There was question in my exam:

```
A single phase transformer 4000/120V 60Hz has the following parameters:
Lm = 450H, Rc = 160K Ohm, L12 = 19uH, L11 = 21mH, R2 = 1.44m Ohm, R1 = 1.6 Ohm
A 4000V source is connected to its primary and it has an inductance Load of 
0.9 ohm and 0.8Lag in the secondary.
a) Find Load Voltage
b) Voltage regulation of transformer
```

My question is about the L12. is it just for confusion because we've got the Lm? if not how the circuit equivalent should be

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how the circuit equivalent should be

[image]

- L11 in your question is Xp in the picture
- Lm in your question is Xm in the picture
- L12 I believe is Xs in the picture
- Rc is Rc

Comment: God -_- I thought that there's a L22 too!